# postgreSql/pgAdmin find where custom type is used in functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm updating my custom postgresql type and I need to find where in functions is my type used/returned. How do I do that? Thank you.

type:

```
-- Type: public.dblchk_picked_qty

-- DROP TYPE public.dblchk_picked_qty;

CREATE TYPE public.dblchk_picked_qty AS
   ("number" text,
    eancode text,
    packageean text,
    name text,
    pickingunit text,
    basicunitsinbox numeric,
    containerid integer,
    ownersordernumber text,
    customerref text);
ALTER TYPE public.dblchk_picked_qty
  OWNER TO nordnet;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've worked it out,

get type oid:

```
SELECT reltype
FROM pg_class  
WHERE relname = 'dblchk_picked_qty'
```

find return type in fuctions by type id:

```
SELECT proname
FROM pg_proc 
WHERE prorettype = 17543
```